# Two promises inside a hash in $q.all

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make two API calls in parallel using `$q.all`, and return both of their responses as one to the controller, and when I break on the return lines for each promise inside the hash, they return the expected data, but it all seem to break when it reaches `$q.all`. This is all in a [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) state, and I'm using resolve to supposedly provide the corresponding controller with the data from `$q.all`

It was originally written in Coffeescript, but here it is in Javascript:

```
      resolve: {
    content: [
      'APIService', function($q, $timeout, APIService) {
        var firstPromise, secondPromise, promises;
        firstPromise = $q.defer();
        secondPromise = $q.defer();
        promises = {
          firstPromise: APIService.get('/some/api/call').then(function(response) {
            return response;
          }),
          secondPromise: APIService.get('/another/api/call').then(function(response) {
            return response;
          })
        };
        $.blockUI();
        $timeout(function() {
          firstPromise.resolve('firstPromise');
          secondPromise.resolve('secondPromise');
        }, 1000);
        $q.all(promises).then(function(responses) {
          $.unblockUI();
          return responses;
        });
        return false;
      }
    ]
  }
```

Please help? I'm using Angular 1.3.15

Comment: Can you check you syntax? You've missed several  `)`

Comment: What do you mean by `<Promises go here>`?

Comment: You should omit **all** of those `.then(id)` invocations. They do *nothing*.

Comment: I've edited the code to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

`content:[` should actually be :

```
resolve: {
  content: function(){
     //      <create promise array>
     return $q.all(promises);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to recreate your logic, but this example works well and hope will help (**Angular 1.3**)

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $q, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = "Superhero"
  var prom1 = $q.defer();
  var prom2 = $q.defer();

  var promises = { 
     prom1: prom1.promise,
     prom2: prom2.promise
  };

  $timeout(function () {
      prom1.resolve('prom1');
      prom2.resolve('prom2');
  }, 1000);

  $q.all(promises).then(function (responces) {
      $scope.prom1 = responces.prom1;
      $scope.prom2 = responces.prom2;
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ugja9gth/1/

Example with **real $http**

http://jsfiddle.net/Evgeniy_D/ugja9gth/2/

Comment: I tried applying your suggestion, and edited my code above, but it still didn't help.

Comment: can you check second fiddle link